# Using JqueryUI menu with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

We're trying to get JqueryUI menus to work in our AngularJS app.
From our Layout.js we're doing the following:

```
OURApp.controller('leftBarCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "../Data/MainPageData",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "Json",
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Acknowledgment) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.subscriptionsModel = data.userSubscriptionsReponse.UserSubscriptionsObjects;
                        $scope.CompanyModel = data.userResponse.CompanyInformation;
                    })
                    $("#mdsubscriptionMenu").menu({
                        menus: "ul",
                        items: "li"
                    });

                }
               .......
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
I read that moving the menu() call to an angular ".directive" restricted to 'A' should do the trick. Is that the only recommended way of getting JqueryUI components to work with AngularJS?

Thanks

Comment: don't mixup jquery with angular, use `$http` instead of `$.ajax` will remove your worry to run `digest` cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of code needs to be in a directive. You shouldn't have jQuery in a controller.

Also you aren't accounting for any rendering time when you try to initialize the plugin outside of `$apply()`. When you are running the plugin code now `$("#mdsubscriptionMenu")` is likely still empty.

It would help to see the view html you are using to render the menu.

You can use the `$last` property of `ng-repeat` to trigger the menu plugin init

Comment: Yep, using the directive and the $last property did the trick! Thanks!